# Typescript error: cannot run ionic2 app when including "@ionic/cloud-angular"

Tags: push-notification, ionic2

I'm trying to do push notifications with an ionic2 app so that I need to import classes from "@ionic/cloud-angular".

However, I got lots of typescript errors in "ionic serve" when doing this, for example:

> TypeScript error:
>   /.../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/@ionic/db/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.d.ts(30,76):
>   Error TS1005: ')' expected. 
>   TypeScript error:
>   /.../ionic2/ionic2-angularfire-sample-master/node_modules/@ionic/db/node_modules/rxjs/scheduler/VirtualTimeScheduler.d.ts(31,1):
>   Error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

These are my information about ionic configuration :

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.10.0
```

And here is my package.json :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "angularfire2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "firebase": "3.3.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.13.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-tslint": "^1.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "^3.10.1",
    "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "name": "fbtest",
  "description": "fbtest: An Ionic project"
}
```

I hope someone could help that I can do to use import "@ionic/cloud-angular". Thank you.

Comment: I suggest upgrading your project to latest ionic 2. Here is a reference to a [package.json](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered trouble the first time I used Ionic Cloud and solved it by reinstalling the Client from scratch. Have you tried to redo the installation step by step? (http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html)

1. Make sure that you have the latest version as suggested: `sudo npm install -g ionic`
2. Create your app ID on your online account with `ionic io init` (this will also modify your ionic.config.json)
3. Modify your app.module.ts like this:

   - Import the modules: `import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';`
   - Define a CloudSettings (don't forget to replace the APP_ID by your own):
     `const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
     'core': {
     'app_id': 'APP_ID'
     }
     };`
   - Inside the imports of your @NgModule, add: `CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)`

*PS: sorry, this maybe go to comment, but I haven't enough reputation points to comment yet.*